# I am trying to write a simple convertor in tkinter but i seem to have a problem with the convert function

Tags: python, tkinter

i am writing a simple unit convertor but it seems like my convert function is working only for the first option. i am looking for some time and cant seem to understand what is wrong in this code.

```
    from tkinter import *
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk

    root = Tk()

    entry = Entry(root, width=30, borderwidth=7, fg="blue")
    entry.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=10, pady=10)

    var_weight = IntVar()
    var_weight.set(1)


    def convert():
        if var_weight == 1:
            global current
            global result
            current = entry.get()
            entry.delete(0, END)
            result = int(current) * 2.20462262
            entry.insert(0, result)
        elif var_weight == 2:
            current = entry.get()
            entry.delete(0, END)
            result = int(current) / 2.20462262
            entry.insert(0, result



    frame = LabelFrame(root, padx=5, pady=5, borderwidth=10)
    frame.grid(row=1, column=2)

    kg = Radiobutton(frame, text="Kg  >>>>   lbs", variable=var_weight, value=1)
    kg.grid(row=1, column=0)
    lbs = Radiobutton(frame, text="lbs  >>>>   Kg", variable=var_weight, value=2)
    lbs.grid(row=3, column=0)
    convert_button_1 = Button(frame, text="Convert", command=convert)
    convert_button_1.grid(row=2, column=3)


    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: how did you get the END variable and whats your output

Answer (score 0):

First you should use `IntVar` instead of `StringVar` for `var_weight`.  Then you need to use `var_weight.get()` instead of `var_weight` in those `if`/`elif` statements.  Also you need to cater empty or invalid input as well using `try`/`except`:

```
var_weight = IntVar() # use IntVar instead of StringVar
var_weight.set(1)

def convert():
    try:
        if var_weight.get() == 1:   # use var_weight.get() instead of var_weight
            current = entry.get()
            entry.delete(0, END)
            result = float(current) * 2.20462262   # use float() instead of int()
            entry.insert(0, result)
        elif var_weight.get() == 2:
            current = entry.get()
            entry.delete(0, END)
            result = float(current) / 2.20462262   # use float() instead of int()
            entry.insert(0, result)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
```